# Arduino parsing JSON

Tags: arduino-mega, json

I have created an API in Ruby on Rails and it send the following JSON response:

```
{"sun_position":{"altitude":"32.46","azimuth":"223.93"}}
```

I'm able to successfully hit the API and store the response. But when I try to parse it and store data it gives me an error. I have used the Arduino JSON library.

The code for parsing the JSON is as follows:

```cpp
bool parseSunPosData(char* content, SunPosData* sunPos) {
  StaticJsonBuffer<JSONBUFFER_SIZE> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(content);
  Serial.println("In parse fuc");
  Serial.println(content);
  Serial.println("==============");
  if (!root.success()) {
    Serial.println("JSON parsing failed!");
    return false;
  }
```

And the output on the serial monitor is as follows:

> In parse fuc 38
>
> {"sun_position":{"altitude":"32.46","azimuth":"223.93"}} 0
>
> ==============
>
> JSON parsing failed! Disconnect

My guess is it can't parse the data due to the numbers 38 and zero printing... I don't know what that is and what it is.

PS: New to Arduino coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have the [HTTP chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) numbers in the content. 38 is the length of the body and it is on the first line of the HTTP body and 0 marks the end.
maybe try using [ArduinoHttpClient](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient.) library for HTTP

Comment: Thanks Juraj, That helped.. I changed the HTTP version to 1.0 from 1.1 and it worked like a charm